# This toggle script I found online only works on the parent id only but not the parents children

Tags: javascript

I have this toggle script and i'm wondering why the red section of this toggle trigger div works only. For example if you click any of the children that are in gold or silver then nothing happens.

So how can I get this to work in a way where any elements that are inside that parent div can also trigger that toggle effect as well.

This is my code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  container.addEventListener('click', function(execute) {
    execute.stopPropagation();
  });

  document.addEventListener('click', closeContainer);

  function closeContainer(obj) {
    var containerVar = document.querySelector('.container');
    if (containerVar.style.display === 'block') {
      containerVar.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (obj.target.id == 'toggle') {
      containerVar.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#toggle{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

#toggle #a{
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle #b{
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
}

  .container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>

<script>
   
</script>

<div id='toggle'>
  <div id='a'>Child</div>
  <div id='b'>Child</div>
</div>

<div class='container'></div><!--</container>-->
```

Comment: because you only run containerVar.style.display = 'block'; which shows .container when obj.target.id == 'toggle' (when you click an element with id toggle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm late to this question but after looking at this post and doing some experiments over time with this script. My method will fix all your problems so I notice that the click listener works well with this script on most devices but devices like Apple mobile devices the click listener does not work with

this script so I realize to get this to work on Apple mobile devices you will have to swap out the click listener for the touchstart listener. I decided the best way to solve this is to detect which device a user is

using and assign the right listener to this script. I constructed conditional statements to assign major mobile devices in using the touchstart listener and other devices will be assigned to use the click listener.

Check this out.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

/******************************************************************************************************
User agent conditionals
******************************************************************************************************/
  
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
  
  var mobile_device='';
  
/*====================================================================================================
Mobile devices
=====================================================================================================*/
  
 //Windows
 /*NOTE: Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"*/
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        var mobile_device= 'yes';
    }
 //
 
 //Android
 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        var mobile_device= 'yes';
  }
//
  
 //IOS
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        var mobile_device= 'yes';
    }
//
  
/******************************************************************************************************
Toggle the target section
******************************************************************************************************/

/*<Assign the compatible trigger for the detected device group>*/

//For general devices
if(mobile_device != 'yes'){
  var device_type_push= 'click';
}
// 
 
 //For targeted mobile devices
else{
 var device_type_push= 'touchstart';
}
//

/*</Assign the compatible trigger for the detected device group>*/


/*<Toggle show the target>*/
  document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener(device_type_push,toggleShowTheTarget);

  function toggleShowTheTarget(event){
    if(document.querySelector('#target').style.display != 'block'){
      document.querySelector('#target').style.display = 'block';
      event.stopPropagation();
     }
  }
/*</Toggle show the target>*/

 
/*<Prevent clicking on the target to toggle hide it self>*/
  document.querySelector('#target').addEventListener(device_type_push,preventClickingOnTheTargetToToggleHideItSelf);
  
 function preventClickingOnTheTargetToToggleHideItSelf(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  }
/*</Prevent clicking on the target to toggle hide it self>*/


/*<Toggle hide the target>*/  
  document.addEventListener(device_type_push,toggleHideTheTarget);
  
  function toggleHideTheTarget() {
    document.querySelector('#target').style.display = 'none';
  }
/*</Toggle hide the target>*/
    
});
```

```css
#toggle{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

#toggle #a{
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle #b{
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
}

  #target {
  background-color: green;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>

<script>
   
</script>

<div id='toggle'>
  <div id='a'>Child</div>
  <div id='b'>Child</div>
</div><!--</toggle>-->

<div id='target'></div><!--</target>-->
```

Comment: Wow this method fixed all my issues that I was having and to make this even better this method works perfectly on Apple devices and on other mobile devices as well, I just tested this method on PC and on mobile devices and it works thank you so much.

Comment: Relying on the user agent string is a technique dating back to 1998 and is well known as what not to do since user agent strings are often not accurate. Instead, you should use Feature Detection. For example ‘if(element.touchstart)...’

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: `if (obj.target.id == 'toggle')`

When you click on the child elements, they become `obj.target` and they do not have an `id` of `toggle`. If you just remove that condition and use a simple `else`, it works.

Also, you had two different variables set up to point to your `.container` element, which is unnecessary. I've corrected that below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var b = document.getElementById("b");  
  
  document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener('click', closeContainer);

  function closeContainer(obj) {
    if (container.style.display === 'block') {
      container.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      container.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    // Check to make sure that the container, the toggle or
    // the child elements were not what was clicked
    if(evt.target !== container && evt.target !== toggle && evt.target !== a && evt.target !== b){
      container.style.display = 'none';
    }
  
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

#toggle #a{
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle #b{
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<div id='toggle'>
  <div id='a'>Child</div>
  <div id='b'>Child</div>
</div>

<div class='container'></div><!--</container>-->
```

And, to go further and make your code more modern and scalable and use less code, don't use inline CSS styles. Instead, set up a CSS class that hides any element it is applied to and simply toggle the use of that class upon each click.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var b = document.getElementById("b");   
  
  document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener('click', toggleContainer);
  
  document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    // Check to make sure that the container, the toggle or
    // the child elements were not what was clicked
    if(evt.target !== container && evt.target !== toggle && evt.target !== a && evt.target !== b){
      container.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  
  });  

  function toggleContainer() { 
    container.classList.toggle("hidden"); // No if/then needed - just toggle.
  }
  
  container.addEventListener('click', function(execute) {
    //execute.stopPropagation();
  });  

});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; } /* Will be applied/removed upon clicks */

#toggle{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

#toggle #a{
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle #b{
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='toggle'>
  <div id='a'>Child</div>
  <div id='b'>Child</div>
</div>
<div class='container hidden'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott Marcus I was going to choose your example as the best answer but I notice there is a bug in your example if you click anywhere in the body it toggles I only wanted the red toggle button and its children to do the toggling but I gave you a point still because I appreciate that you put your time in trying to help me out.

Comment: @fsofb I was just going off the code you provided, which was setting up the `click` event on `document`. We just change the event handling setup from `document` to the `toggle` element. I'll update the code.

Comment: Here's the tricky part that I notice your example cant do right now but I should of mentioned this earlier so my bad so lets just say I use that red div button to toggle to show or hide that green container do you know a way where I can press any where outside of that green container so that green container will disappear as well?

Comment: @fsofb Yes, we just set up an event handler on the document that checks to make sure you didn't click on the div and we hide the element. I'll update, but you should ask all these things in your original question.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize all these things till later and the other users method did not work on mobile safari his method works on all the browsers except mobile safari so I hope your update will work on mobile safari as well. :( Sorry for the mess guys.

Comment: Your method works thank you but it has the same effect as @maxpelic but for some reason this works only on PC and on Android so this does not work on mobile safari. Any ideas how I can get this to work on mobile safari? I'm referring to that method where you click any where outside of that green container to hide it. or do you think I should ask another question based on how to get that feature working on mobile Safari? Or should I just stick to this post still?

Comment: I don't want to make this complicated by going outside of the scope of my original question so I decided to ask another question on how I can fix that feature on mobile Safari but I appreciate your help. At least future readers can decide which method works for them in this post so thank for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you check the ID of the event target, it will return the ID of the element clicked, not it's parent. You can add a line of code to check if the target element's parent has the 'toggle' ID (`obj.target.id == 'toggle' || obj.target.parentElement.id === 'toggle'`) or it might be easier to add an event listener to the toggle element instead (see the example below)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  container.addEventListener('click', function(execute) {
    execute.stopPropagation();
  });

  document.addEventListener('click', closeContainer);
  
  document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    //this event will be called if the element with the 'toggle' ID or any of its children are clicked
    var containerVar = document.querySelector('.container');
    if(container.style.display !== 'block'){
      //show container
      container.style.display = 'block';
      //prevent the document click listener from being triggered
      event.stopPropagation();
     }
  });

  function closeContainer(obj) {
    var containerVar = document.querySelector('.container');
    containerVar.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
```

```css
#toggle{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

#toggle #a{
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle #b{
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
}

  .container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>

<script>
   
</script>

<div id='toggle'>
  <div id='a'>Child</div>
  <div id='b'>Child</div>
</div>

<div class='container'></div><!--</container>-->
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this and sorry to bug you but this does not work on mobile safari any way you know how to make this work on mobile safari the toggle trigger works but I can no longer click any where outside of that green container to also hide that green container. Your method works on all browsers except on mobile safari. :(

Comment: That's really weird - did the original code hide it on mobile Safari?

Comment: I just tested this on a android device and it works but for some reason this does not work on the iPhone's mobile safari and yes I notice only the toggle button worked in my original code example to but not the method of hiding that green container by clicking outside of it. I just notice that sorry any ideas how I can get this to work on mobile safari? I'm referring to that method where you click any where outside of that green container to hide it. or do you think I should ask another question based on how to get that feature working on mobile Safari? Or should I stick to this post still?

Comment: I don't want to make this complicated by going outside of the scope of my original question so I decided to ask another question on how I can fix that feature on mobile Safari so I'll give you this best answer back to you sorry about going outside of the scope of this question. I appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: No problem - try adding the event listener to the window instead of the document

Comment: Window did not work but I figure out how I can get this to work on mobile safari but I ran into another problem now if I press the toggle button each time then the  green container disappears and reappears by each toggle button press so that is my new problem now. This what I did.